# How to validate the two field in one object using react hook with yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup, react-hook-form

```
{
        label: 'Room',
        name: 'room',
        rule: yup.array(yup.object()).required(),
        renderer: (data: any) => {
          const { control, register, errors } = useFormContext();
          
          return (
            <div className="block w-full">
              {
                teacherRole && teacherRole.map((item, idx) => (
                  <div key={idx} className="flex pb-2 items-center">
                    <SelectPicker
                      placeholder={'TEACHER'}
                      data={
                        teacherList && teacherList.map(x => (
                          { label: x.name, value: x.id }
                        ))
                      }
                      onChange={(val) => control.setValue('room', setTeacher(val, idx))}
                      value={control.getValues()['selectTeacher']}
                      style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    />
                    <span className="px-2 leading-8 text-2xl">-</span>
                    <SelectPicker
                      data={[
                        { label: 'Admin', value: 'ROLE_ADMIN' },
                        { label: 'Teacher', value: 'ROLE_TEACHER' },
                        { label: 'Student', value: 'ROLE_STUDENT' },
                      ]}
                      placeholder={'Role'}
                      onChange={(val) => control.setValue('room', setRole(val, idx))}
                      value={control.getValues()['selectRole']}
                      style={{ width: '100%', paddingRight: '.3rem' }}
                    />
                  </div>
                ))
              }
            </div>
          )
        }
      }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to validate the teacher and the room when its empty.
cause when I try to submit the form, even its null it will submit.

What I want is to add a validation when the role or teacher is null the error message should be appear.

Comment: Well, first things first, you don't close the string on the first line, so pretty much the whole object is invalid.

Comment: @samuei already updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the type of `teacher` and `role` so I assumed it. Hope this ex help.

```
  Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        teacher: Yup.string().required("teacher required"),
        role: Yup.string()
          .required("role required")
      })
    )
  })
```

Comment: How it will appear the error message on the select element?

Comment: You can get the errors from the form context and show them.

Comment: I tried to console the errors, but it only display ```room: { message: "room must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `""`).
 If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`"}```

Comment: How do to display the two select type?

Comment: I think it's because the init value of room, should change it to `[]` instead of `""`

Comment: What do you mean `display the two select type`?